# Find height values of 2 divs, add together and apply it to top position of another div

Tags: jquery

I need to find the `height` of 2 `divs`, add the two values together and then apply it to the `top` position of another `div`.

I've tried 2 methods and neither seem to work

`$('.horizScroll').css('top',$('.frame').height()+$('.frame1').height());`

```
var frameHeight = $('.frame').height();
var frameHeight1 = $('.frame1').height();
var topTotal = parseInt(frameHeight) + parseInt(frameHeight1);
var topPos = $('.horizScroll').css('top');
topTotal = topPos;
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML mark-up that goes with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var frameHeight = $('.frame').height();
var frameHeight1 = $('.frame1').height();
var topTotal = parseInt(frameHeight) + parseInt(frameHeight1);
$('.horizScroll').css('top', topTotal);
```